# Create blank plist programmatically (in DocumentsDirectory)

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, bundle, createfile

Normally I save data to a plist (just data that I don't really care if a JailBroken phone hacked, like users preferences and stuff) except when the user first launches the app I create the plist like so:

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *pathFirstTime = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FirstTime.plist"];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: pathFirstTime])
{
    NSString *bundleFirstTime = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FirstTime" ofType:@"plist"];

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundleFirstTime toPath:pathFirstTime error:&error];
}
```

So I create a blank plist file in xcode and put it in the bundle and the first time the user launches the app it copies it to the documentsDirectory...

Is there anyway I can create the blank plist file in objective-c the first time that way I don't actually have to create one in Xcode and have it in the bundle but it will just get created automatically the first time the user launches the app...

Basically just avoiding this code: `[fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundleFirstTime toPath:pathFirstTime error:&error];`

Comment: [Do not use signatures, salutations or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 4):

```
[@{} writeToFile: pathFirstTime atomically: NO];
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` instance and use `writeToFile:atomically:`.

Answer (score 0):

remove your whole code, this will do the trick

```
    if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FirstRun"]){
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *pathFirstTime = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyPlistFile.plist"];

            [@{} writeToFile: pathFirstTime atomically: YES];

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"FirstRun"];
        }
```

**Want to add a new record ?**

```
        NSString *pathFirstTime = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyPlistFile.plist"];
        NSMutableDictionary *mdic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:pathFirstTime]];

        [mdic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3] forKey:@"user-selected-color-scheme"];
        [mdic writeToFile: pathFirstTime atomically: YES];
```

**Read the plist file later ?**

```
        NSString *pathFirstTime = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyPlistFile.plist"];
        NSMutableDictionary *mdic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:pathFirstTime]];
        NSLog(@"%@", mdic);
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what this part is doing? `if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FirstRun"]){`

Comment: Is it checking the plist file? I'm just a little confused on what your code is doing... What is `NSUserDefaults`?

Comment: How do I assign other keys to my plist with your code? (For example: `user-selected-color-scheme = 3`)?

Comment: How is this better than the one OP suggested?

Comment: 1) this part if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FirstRun"]) is used to check whether this is the first run of the application. You wanted to check that.